# reload data on select change - Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to reload my treetable when I change my select option. I tried reloading OnInit method but it doesn't work. 
This is my component, the service _estadoService calls function which calls a web service.

```ts
constructor(
      private _route: ActivatedRoute,
      private _router: Router,
      private _estadoService: EstadoService
  ) {
    this.titulo = 'Estado de Ingresos y Gastos:';
    this.year = 2017;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let TodayDate = new Date();
    this.mes = TodayDate.getMonth();
    this.listaAnios = this.getYears();
    this.listaMonths = this.getMonths();
    this.listaMonthsNames = this.getMonthsNames();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.listaMonths.length; i++) {
      this.finalarr[i] = [this.listaMonths[i],this.listaMonthsNames[i]];
    }

    let sess = localStorage.getItem('datos');
    let datos = sess.split(" ");

    this._estadoService.getEstado(datos[1],this.year).subscribe(
      result => { console.log(result);
        this.children = result.Costos.ItemCosto;
        this.estados = this.getNewData(this.children);
        this.estados = this.getFirstLevel(this.estados, '0');
        this.list_Init = result.Costos.ItemCosto;
        this.obj = this.createTree(null, this.children);
        this.datos= this.obj[0];
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }

onChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.year = value;
    ngOnInit();
}
```

this is my HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="anio"(change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let list of listaAnios" [ngValue]="list">{{list}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="allMonths">Ver todos los meses:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="allMonths" id="allMonths" [ngModel]="" (ngModelChange)="showAll($event)">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div *ngIf="!estados">
  Cargando Listado de Pagos...
</div>
<div *ngIf="estados" class="table-responsive col-lg-12 tablilla">
  <div>
    <ay-treeTable [value]="datos.data">
      <ay-column field="nom_item" header="Ingresos y Gastos"></ay-column>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let month of finalarr | slice: this.listaMonthsNames.length - this.check">
        <ay-column field="{{month[0]}}" header="{{month[1]}}"> {{month[0]}} </ay-column>
      </ng-container>

    </ay-treeTable>
  </div>
</div>
```

id like to refresh my treetable when I change the option on the select. any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call ngOnInit lifecycle method from other methods in your component. If what you want is to execute all the logic again when the option of the select is changed, you could do the following:

```
constructor(
  private _route: ActivatedRoute,
  private _router: Router,
  private _estadoService: EstadoService
) {
  this.titulo = 'Estado de Ingresos y Gastos:';
  this.year = 2017;
}

ngOnInit() {
  updateData();
}

updateData() {
  let TodayDate = new Date();
  this.mes = TodayDate.getMonth();
  this.listaAnios = this.getYears();
  this.listaMonths = this.getMonths();
  this.listaMonthsNames = this.getMonthsNames();

  for (var i = 0; i < this.listaMonths.length; i++) {
    this.finalarr[i] = [this.listaMonths[i],this.listaMonthsNames[i]];
  }

  let sess = localStorage.getItem('datos');
  let datos = sess.split(" ");

  this._estadoService.getEstado(datos[1],this.year).subscribe(
    result => { console.log(result);
      this.children = result.Costos.ItemCosto;
      this.estados = this.getNewData(this.children);
      this.estados = this.getFirstLevel(this.estados, '0');
      this.list_Init = result.Costos.ItemCosto;
      this.obj = this.createTree(null, this.children);
      this.datos= this.obj[0];
    },
    error => {
      console.log(<any>error);
    }
  );
}

onChange(value) {
  console.log(value);
  this.year = value;
  updateData();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't change the HTML (treetable)

Comment: it works, however, i didn't notice my variable this.datos was equaled to this.obj[0] instead of the last element push to the array.